# How to split the files based on size in ssis script task

Tags: ssis, script-task

How to split the files based on size in ssis script task? I tried in many ways but iam not getting the exact script for this.

Comment: Please expand a bit more; what kind of file? what are the splitting criteria? also please include a sample of the files and the code you have tried.

Comment: Are you asking to split destination files based on maximum number of records per file?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Iam extracting all the tables  into CSV Format Dynamically for that Iam using Script task. For one of the table i.e Sales table the data is huge so for that i need to split the data into number of files based on size.Each file should have only 250mb and second file should should start from 251 to 500 mb like that it has to split and it should have only 250 mb. I need to split the data in Soucre itself not based on rows.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).